# Meteor collectionfs insert server side

Tags: javascript, meteor, gridfs, meteorite

hi everyone i using collectionfs + gridfs + cfs filesystem,
on collectionfs documentation i find how to insert file on client side like this :

```
Template.myForm.events({
  'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        //Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
      });
    });
  }
});
```

on that case will insert file on client side, but in my case i remove insecure, so can't do insert on client side, i try to make it on server side . so this is my code :

```
Template.myForm.events({
    'change . myFileInput': function (event, template) {
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (fileLoadEvent) {
                Meteor.call('ImageUpload', file, reader.result, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        alert(res);
                    }
                });
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);


        });
    }
});
```

server.js :

```
Meteor.methods({
    ImageUpload: function (fileInfo, fileData) {
        console.log(fileInfo);
        Images.insert(fileInfo, fileData, function (err, fileObj) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            else {
                //Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
                console.log(fileObj);
                return fileObj._id;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

but it still doesn't work, please help me how to fix this.
how to insert on server side?

Comment: It is not working on client side because you have to define allow/deny rules. I recommend you to do it on clientside ;) Check the meteor docs.

Comment: :o but i remove insecure, so cant insert from client, it always error

Comment: Did you defined allow/deny rules?

Comment: Oops sorry i dont know about that, where i must define it? May be there is an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example for you. I didnt tested it but it shows the way you have to go.

First define a collection:

I think this step is already clear to you.

```
var postImagesStoreFS = new FS.Store.FileSystem("postImages", {
  path: "~/workspace/uploads/"
});
```

Add added some filters. Just in case you need something like that.

```
PostImages = new FS.Collection('postImages', {
  stores: [postImagesStoreFS ],
  filter: {
  maxSize: 3145728,
  allow: {
    contentTypes: ['image/*'],
    extensions: ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG']
  }
});
```

Now you can define in the same *.js file your allow and deny functions. If you remove the insecure package all inserts/updates/removes have to pass allow/deny functions. If a command passes the allow callback it can be inserted into your collection (If there is no deny function that invalidates it)

Well in this example i just like to insert an image if there is a user and if the metadata user of the image is the user itself. You have to set the metadata user on your own. For testing just return true in every allow function, like shown in the example of Pent. Check the meteor documentation to read more about allow/deny http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

```
PostImages.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return (userId && doc.metadata.owner === userId);
  },
  update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return (userId === doc.metadata.owner);
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return false;
  },
  download: function(userId) {
    return !!userId;
  }
});
```

The client template should work as you posted. Just in case you want to use some metadata i added a bigger example.

```
Template.myForm.events({
  'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      var fsFile = new FS.File(file);
      fsFile.metadata = {owner: Meteor.userId()};
      Images.insert(fsFile, function (err, fileObj) {

      });
    });
  }
});
```

This should be everything you need to have.

Comment: wow thanks it works, but why i have this error? http://localhost:3000/cfs/files/postImages/i2uWz6MHNxqRbcBjA/heart.png?store=postImages 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: why the url to be forbidden?

Comment: Where do you get the url from?

Comment: chaosbohne, can you confirm your getting metadata in the allow rule? I'm using gridfs for this, setting the metadata (and can see it in the database) but if I console.log(doc) in the allow rule, I don't see any metadata.

Comment: You have to set the metadata on clientside in your event. See my example or https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#add-custom-metadata-to-a-file-before-inserting for another example. Attention the metadata has to be set to a new FS.File instance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to apply allow and deny rules like so:

```
Images.allow({
  insert: function() { return true },
  update: function() { return true },
  remove: function() { return false }
});
```

Update must also be applied if using streaming

Comment: This is fine if all you want to do is test, not great from a security point of view if you want to control who can change things.

Comment: This is for allowing public uploads and assuming no user accounts, just like imgur