# AWS S3 Bucket Upload using CollectionFS and cfs-s3 meteor package

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor

I am using Meteor.js with Amazon S3 Bucket for uploading and storing photos. I am using the meteorite packges collectionFS and aws-s3. I have setup my aws-s3 connection correctly and the images collection is working fine.

Client side event handler:

```
     'click .submit': function(evt, templ) {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        var photoFile = $('#photoInput').get(0).files[0];

        if(photoFile){

        var readPhoto = new FileReader();

        readPhoto.onload = function(event) {
            photodata = event.target.result;
            console.log("calling method");
            Meteor.call('uploadPhoto', photodata, user);
        };
      }
```

And my server side method:

```
 'uploadPhoto': function uploadPhoto(photodata, user) {

      var tag = Random.id([10] + "jpg");
      var photoObj = new FS.File({name: tag});
      photoObj.attachData(photodata);
      console.log("s3 method called");

      Images.insert(photoObj, function (err, fileObj) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err, err.stack)
        }else{
          console.log(fileObj._id);
        }
      });
```

The file that is selected is a .jpg image file but upon upload I get this error on the server method:

*Exception while invoking method 'uploadPhoto' Error: DataMan constructor received data that it doesn't support*

And no matter whether I directly pass the image file, or attach it as data or use the fileReader to read as text/binary/string. I still get that error. Please advise.

Comment: Is there a reason you dont want to make the insert clientside?

Comment: maybe it is the wrong approach - but to keep my AWS credentials (key + secret) secure and not give it to the client. Would also want to do certain validations on the data, server side before allowing an upload to the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, maybe some thoughts. I have done things with collectionFS some months ago, so take care to the docs, because my examples maybe not 100% correct.

Credentials should be set via environment variables. So your key and secret is available on server only. Check this [link](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables) for further reading.

Ok first, here is some example code which is working for me. Check yours for differences.

Template helper:

```
'dropped #dropzone': function(event, template) {
  addImage(event);
}
```

Function addImage:

```
function addImagePreview(event) {
  //Go throw each file,
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {    

    //Some Validationchecks
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {

        var fsFile = new FS.File(image.src);

        //setMetadata, that is validated in collection
        //just own user can update/remove fsFile
        fsFile.metadata = {owner: Meteor.userId()};           

        PostImages.insert(fsFile, function (err, fileObj) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });         
      };
    })(file);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);          
  });   
}
```

Ok, your next point is the validation. The validation can be done with allow/deny rules and with a filter on the FS.Collection. This way you can do all your validation AND insert via client.

Example:

```
PostImages = new FS.Collection('profileImages', {
  stores: [profileImagesStore],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 3145728,
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*'],
      extensions: ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG']
    }
  },
  onInvalid: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
});


PostImages.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return (userId && doc.metadata.owner === userId);
  },
  update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return (userId === doc.metadata.owner);
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return false;
  },
  download: function(userId) {
    return true;
  },
  fetch: []
});
```

Here you will find another example [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044259/meteor-collectionfs-insert-server-side)

Another point of error is maybe your aws configuration. Have you done everything like it is written [here](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3)?

Based on this post [click](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/206) it seems that this error occures when FS.File() is not constructed correctly. So maybe this should be you first way to start.

A lot for reading so i hope this helps you :)

Comment: thanks for this. just working through this. environment variables certainly do work.

Comment: this does work - the only issue is that the contentType seems to be default back to application/octet-stream upon upload to S3. Although the type in the FS.File is clearly image/jpeg or image/png.